# Submitting multiple check-box selection in ASP.NET MVC form with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with textboxes, dropdownlists and checkboxes. I have the challenge of submitting several checkbox items into the database. The data did submit but it only submits the last checked item on the form.

Here's is my UI

```
<div class="block type-3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row post animated fadeInUp">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-block">
                <div ng-controller="tutorequestController">
                    <form name="tutrequestform" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-text">Required fields are <span class="text-blue">*</span>. Fill out the form and we'll contact you soon</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.firstname" name="firstname" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Firstname *" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Lastname *" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.phonenumber" name="phonenumber" type="number" class="form-input" placeholder="Phone Number *" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.phonenumber2" name="phonenumber2" type="number" class="form-input" placeholder="Re-type Phone Number *" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.emailaddress" name="emailaddress" type="email" class="form-input" placeholder="Email Address *" required />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div ng-controller="stateLGAController">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                        <!--<select ng-change="GetStateLgas()" ng-options="moreState as moreState.state1 for moreState in moreStates track by moreState.state_id" ng-model="select" class="form-input"><option>Select Your State</option></select>-->
                                        <select ng-model="tutorRequest.state_id" ng-change="GetStateLgasByid(tutorRequest.state_id)"
                                                ng-options="moreState.state_id as moreState.state1 for moreState in moreStates" class="form-input">
                                            <option>Select Your State</option>
                                        </select><!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                        <select ng-model="tutorRequest.lga_id"
                                                ng-options="lga.lga_id as lga.local_govt for lga in stateLGA" class="form-input">
                                            <option>Select Your L.G.A</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <textarea ng-model="tutorRequest.address" class="form-input" name="address" placeholder="House Address *" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.numofchild" name="numofchild" class="form-input">
                                    <option value='Select-Number-of-Child-for-Tutor'>Select number of Child/ren for Tutor</option>
                                    <option value='1'>1</option>
                                    <option value='2'>2</option>
                                    <option value='3'>3</option>
                                    <option value='4'>4</option>
                                    <option value='5'>5</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.classrangeandage" class="form-input" name="classrangeandage" type="text" required placeholder="Class range of each child and age respectively *" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 form-text">
                                <span  class="text-blue">What subject would the tutor teach? Tick appropriate subject below.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="subjectController">
                                <div ng-repeat="sub in tutorRequest.tutorsubject" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="chBoxPad">
                                        <input ng-model="tutorRequest.tutorsubject[$index].checked" type="checkbox" id="{{sub.sub_id}}" name="{{sub.subject1+'_'+$index}}" ng-change="updateChecked()" />
                                        <label for="{{sub.sub_id}}"><span></span>{{sub.subject1}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.preferredsexoftutor" name="sex" id="sex" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="preferredsexoftutor" selected="selected">Preferred Sex of Tutor</option>
                                    <option value="any">Any</option>
                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.childcurrentschool" name="childcurrentschool" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Current School of Child *" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.schoolcurriculum" name="schoolcurriculum" id="curi" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="">What curriculum does the school use</option>
                                    <option value="Not Sure">Not Sure</option>
                                    <option value="British Curriculum">British Curriculum</option>
                                    <option value="American Curriculum">American Curriculm</option>
                                    <option value="Nigerian Curriculum">Nigerian Curriculum</option>
                                    <option value="Combination of British and Nigerian">Combination of British and Nigerian</option>
                                    <option value="Question doesnt apply to me">Question doesn't apply to me</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.urgencyoftutor" name="urgencyoftutor" id="urgencyoftutor" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="">Urgency of tutor</option>
                                    <option value="Urgently" selected="selected">Urgently</option>
                                    <option value="In 1 Week">In a Week</option>
                                    <option value="In 2 Weeks">In 2 Weeks</option>
                                    <option value="In a Month">In a Month</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.calltime" name="calltime" id="calltime" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">What time of the day would you like to be called</option>
                                    <option value="Anytime">Anytime</option>
                                    <option value="8 to 12">Morning - between 8am and 12noon</option>
                                    <option value="12 to 3">Afternoon - between 12noon to 3pm</option>
                                    <option value=" 3 to 6">Evening - between 3pm to 6pm</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.frequencyoftutor" name="frequencyoftutor" id="frequencyoftutor" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="">How many times a week would you like the tutor to come</option>
                                    <option value="1">Once a week</option>
                                    <option value="2">2 times a week</option>
                                    <option value="3">3 times a week</option>
                                    <option value="4">4 times a week</option>
                                    <option value="5">5 times a week</option>
                                    <option value="6">6 times a week</option>
                                    <option value="7">7 times a week</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.tutorhrs" name="tutorhrs" id="tutorhrs" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="">How many hours per day should tutoring hold</option>
                                    <option value="1" selected="selected">1 hr</option>
                                    <option value="2">2 hrs</option>
                                    <option value="3">3 hrs</option>
                                    <option value="4">4 hrs</option>
                                    <option value="5">5 hrs</option>
                                    <option value="6">6 hrs</option>
                                    <option value="7">7 hrs</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <input ng-model="tutorRequest.goal" name="goal" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Specific goal for tutoring session" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <select ng-model="tutorRequest.howdidyouhearaboutus" name="howdidyouhearaboutus" class="form-input">
                                    <option value="">How did you hear about us</option>
                                    <option value="Google" selected="selected">Google</option>
                                    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                                    <option value="I got an SMS from Prepschool">I got an SMS from Prepschool</option>
                                    <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                                    <option value="Nairaland">Nairaland</option>
                                    <option value="I saw a flyer">I saw a flyer</option>
                                    <option value="Prepschool Brochure">Prepschool Brochure</option>
                                    <option value="A friend / member of household">A friend / member of household</option>
                                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <span class="button">
                                <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-click="CreateTutRequest(tutorRequest, tutrequestform.$valid)">Submit Request</button>
                            </span>
                            <!--<td><input type="submit" ng-click="CreateEmployee(Emp, myForm.$valid)" value="Create" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" ng-click="UpdateEmployee(Emp)" value="Update" /></td>-->
                            <span class="success"></span>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the a partial graphical representation of the UI in image format.
[image]
And here's my angularJs controller for the page.

```
myApp.factory('crudServiceTutorrequest', function ($http) {
    // Create an object and start adding methods to the object.
    crudTutRObj = {};

    // Add create method to the crudTutRObj
    crudTutRObj.getAll = function () {
        var tutorRequests;

        tutorRequests = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Tutorrequest/Index' }).
        then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return tutorRequests;
    }

    crudTutRObj.getStates = function () {
        var ddlStates;

        ddlStates = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/States/Index' }).
        then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return ddlStates;
    }

    crudTutRObj.getSubject = function () {
        var Subjects;

        Subjects = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Subject/Index' }).
        then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return Subjects;
    }

    crudTutRObj.createTutRequest = function (tutRequest) {
        var tutorRequest;

        tutorRequest = $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/Tutorrequest/Create', data: tutRequest }).
            then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        return tutorRequest;
    }

    crudTutRObj.getById = function (id) { }

    crudTutRObj.update = function (fms) { }

    crudTutRObj.deleteById = function (id) { }

    return crudTutRObj;
});

myApp.controller('tutorequestController', function ($scope, crudServiceTutorrequest) {

    // Get all tutorRequests
    //crudServiceTutorrequest.getAll().then(function (result) {
    //    $scope.tutorRequests = result;
    //})

    // Get data for states to populate the states dropdownlist
    crudServiceTutorrequest.getStates().then(function (result) {
        $scope.moreStates = result;
    })   

    // Submit the form with the create function
    $scope.CreateTutRequest = function (tutorRequest) {
        crudServiceTutorrequest.createTutRequest(tutorRequest).then(function (result) {
            $scope.Msg = "Tutor Request has been submitted successfully!";
        });
    }
});

myApp.controller('stateLGAController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.GetStateLgas = function () {
        $http({ method: 'Get', url: '/StateLGA/Index' })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.stateLGA = response.data;
        });
    };

    $scope.GetStateLgasByid = function (state_id) {
        $http({ method: 'Get', url: '/StateLGA/GetlgaByStateid/' + state_id })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.stateLGA = response.data;
        });
    };
});

angular.module("app", []).controller('subjectController', ['$scope', function ($scope, crudServiceTutorrequest) {
    var subjects;
    subjects = crudServiceTutorrequest.getSubject().then(function (result) {
        $scope.subjects = result;
    })

    $scope.tutorRequest = {
        tutorsubject: subjects
    };

    angular.forEach($scope.subjects, function (subject) {
        var sub = angular.merge({ checked: false }, subject);
        $scope.tutorRequest.tutorsubject.push(sub);
    });

    $scope.allSubjectChecked = [];
    $scope.updateChecked = function () {
        console.log($scope.tutorRequest.tutorsubject);
        $scope.allSubjectChecked = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.tutorRequest.tutorsubject, function (sub) {
            if (sub.checked) {

                $scope.allSubjectChecked.push(sub);
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

And finally, the js file is routes all the pages to the ng-view

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Department', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/Admin/Department/Department.html',
        controller: 'departmentController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Employee', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/Admin/Employee/Employee.html',
        controller: 'employeeController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Aboutus', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/User/Aboutus/Aboutus.html',
        controller: ''
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Contactus', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/User/Contactus/Contactus.html',
        controller: ''
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Tutorregistration', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/User/Tutorregistration/Tutorregistration.html',
        controller: ''
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Tutorrequest', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/User/Tutorrequest/Tutorrequest.html',
        controller: 'tutorequestController'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Home',
        templateUrl:'Templates/User/Home/Home.html'
    });
});
```

Would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Are you sure sub.subject1 is different for each item?

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84 : Yes...sub.subject1 is different for each item. That is the actual name of the check box and also what is displayed in the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems lie in the fact that you put the same ng-model for every subject. Angular don't build an array for a list of checkboxes, you have to bind every checkbox to a separate model.

The best way of doing that is to initialize you tutorsubject with all the values possible and a field 'checked' set to false like this :

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.tutorRequest = {tutorsubject : [{sub_id:1, subject1:"Foo"},
                                     {sub_id:2, subject1:"Foo2"}]};
    angular.forEach($scope.subjects,function(subject){          
          var sub = angular.merge({checked:false}, subject);
          $scope.tutorRequest.tutorsubject.push(sub);
    });
  
  $scope.allSubjectChecked = [];
  $scope.updateChecked = function(){
    console.log($scope.tutorRequest.tutorsubject);
    $scope.allSubjectChecked = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.tutorRequest.tutorsubject, function(sub){
        if(sub.checked){

            $scope.allSubjectChecked.push(sub);
        }
    });
  }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>  

 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="sub in tutorRequest.tutorsubject" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="chBoxPad" >
            <input ng-model="tutorRequest.tutorsubject[$index].checked" type="checkbox" id="{{sub.sub_id}}" name="{{sub.subject1+'_'+$index}}" ng-change="updateChecked()"/>
             <label for="{{sub.sub_id}}"><span></span>{{sub.subject1}}</label>
         </div>
    </div>
    <h2> Subject selected : </h2>
    <div ng-repeat="selected in allSubjectChecked">
      <span ng-bind="selected.subject1"></span><br/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Of course if this way of storing the data don't match to your backend; you can filter them when submitting the form. In order to not change the model displayed when doing that, perform this in the result of a `var myData = angular.merge({},$scope.tutorRequest);`

EDIT : change sample code by working snippet

Comment: angularJs creates a different scope for each ng-repeat, so the fact that they share the same model name is irrelevant in this case

Comment: @Walfrat: The check-box which is populated from the database is not showing. So there's no way to even check on teh check-box field to test your solution.

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84 your answer is the irrelevant one here, ng-repeat create one child scope of the current one for each element, so the ng-model is bound of the controller's scope's model, not to ng-repeat one, otherwise he wouldn't be able to get eh value when submitting the form

Comment: @Walfrat: The $index in `name="{{sub.subject1+'_'+$index}}"` is not needed as the names of the check-box items from the database is different.So if left  `name="{{sub.subject1}}"` would be just ok however i concur with  `ng-model="tutorRequest.tutorsubject[$index].checked" ` portion of the code. I still don;t understand why the checkbox are not being populated from the database with your solution.

Comment: I missed something. I just edit my post with a working snippet. It was because i had no list `subjects` since everything is in `tutorRequest.tutorsubject`. Having one name different by checkbox is a requirement of HTML, this may not be a problem here, but if you add some validation logic later on here or somewhere else, you'll have problem, so better to get used to it. Note : i removed `ng-true/false-value` because they put strings in the model instead of booleans

Comment: @Walfrat: Thanks a bunch! I tried integrating your solution into what I already have, the end result was more confusion. I'm i to add the angular.module to my .js file? or take a the relevant portion which is from `.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){` down to `}]);` and add it in my code? Let me update my question to reflect your implementation if that will help.

Comment: include it in your own controller, i needed the angular module and controller to make the demo working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112145/discussion-between-guzzyman-and-walfrat).

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that MVC doesn't bind a checkbox value if it's false. Try this instead:

```
<div ng-controller="subjectController">
    <div ng-repeat="sub in subjects" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="chBoxPad">
            <input ng-model="tutorRequest.tutorsubject" type="checkbox" id="{{sub.sub_id}}" name="{{sub.subject1}}" ng-true-value="{{sub.sub_id}}" />
            <input type="hidden" value="false" name="{{sub.subject1}}" />
            <label for="{{sub.sub_id}}"><span></span>{{sub.subject1}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the checkbox is false, the hidden field will be submitted. Instead, when it's true, two fields will be submitted at the same time (false and true) and MVC will get that as a "true" value.

I know it sounds odd, but that it how MVC works. You can see that yourself if you use @Html.CheckBoxFor(). You'll have the same output.

Comment: we're talking of angularJs here and not mvc view. That code you see there is populated from the database.  The interface has about 31 checkbox especially when previewed. The challenge I have is it only submits the last checked value into the database.

Comment: What do you mean "we're talking of angularJs here and not mvc view"? You're using MVC to post the form, no? You're gonna have a Controller, with a Post Action... no? If so, try my solution and debug that action when you submit the form. You should have the values.

Comment: Thanks for your solution however, your solution is not working. The checkboxes are not displaying both on internet explorer and google chrome however, when I placed the hidden field after the label, it displayed but items are not submitted into the database.